# Configure tcServer in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, tcserver

How can I configure `tcServer` in `Hybris`?

I have found the `tcServer` setting in `/bin/platform/project.properties`, which properties need to be configured?

```
tomcat.context.template=${HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR}/tomcat/tomcat_context.tpl

# The directory into which files created by "ant production" are created
#production.output.path=${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}/hybrisServer

# Choose the type of server: tomcat or tcserver
bundled.server.type=tcserver

# Absolute path to tomcat
#bundled.tomcat.home=${platformhome}/tomcat

#Version of tomcat server
#bundled.tomcat.version=7.0.52

# Absolute path to tcserver
bundled.tcserver.home=${HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR}/tcServer

# tcserver's tomcat version
bundled.tcserver.tomcat.version=7.0.42.A.RELEASE

# Relative path to tcserver's tomcat
bundled.tcserver.tomcat.home=tomcat-${bundled.tcserver.tomcat.version}

# Name of an server instance
#bundled.tcserver.instance=instance1

# Name of an instance template to use: hybris or hybris_insight
bundled.tcserver.template=hybris


production.output.path=${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}/hybrisServer
```

Comment: question is unclear. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: by default hybris runs on tomact but i would like to run on tcServer?  plz tel steps to configure it

Answer (score 1):

> Since version 5.1, hybris no longer ship the
>   tcserver embedded with the hybris Platform. In order to use tc Server
>   you need to install it independently and configure the hybris Platform
>   to use this server.

**Enable SpringSource tcServer :**

Prior to version 5.1, the SpringSource tcServer is shipped with the hybris Platform. To enable it you have to:

1. Open local.properties file.
2. For the bundled.server.type property, set the value tcserver.
3. Set the bundled.tcserver.instance property.
4. call `ant deploy` or `ant all` (which already includes the deploy call), for deploying configuration files from your {HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR}/tcServer/conf folder to the tcSServer instance. If SpringSource tcServer instance has not been created yet, it is created by deployment process implicitly.

**Run SpringSource tcServer**

1. On Windows: Call
   tcserver.bat instance_name
   from platform's bin directory.
2. On Linux: Call
   ./tcserver.sh instance_name
   from platform's bin directory.

Remember to replace instance_name with actual name of tcServer's instance to be run.

For More Details, Follow this link :

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/SpringSource+tcServer

Comment: i did this but on server start up i an finding server=tomcat only